# How do I group a few fields to one indicator to reference later in Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, vba, filtering

Note: I'm pretty new to VBA. 
I'm trying to create an **Or** feature to our custom Filter where users can have an option to filter one or another. I'm thinking user needs to select all three Field, Comparison and Criteria to make it one selection and then when **Or** button is hit another selection will be generated and so on... until click on the **Filter** button. I have the code on the Filter which does work so far.

[image]
This is just a silly draft I have so far 
    Private Sub cmdOr_Click()

```
    Dim selectOr As Integer
```

> ***Here I'm not sure how to set these three fields to one indicator***

```
    selectOr = Field & Comparison & Criteria

    If IsNull(selectOr) Then
        MsgBox "All three fields, Comparison and Criteria must be selected", vbOKCancel, "Filter"
    Else
```

> ***Here I want to increment my `selectOr` so that users can select as many `Or` option as they can***

```
        selectOr 1
End Sub
```

I hope I'm being clear, if not please let me know! Thanks!

Here is what I have in my filter button so far. Note: there is dictionaries, collections other modules used.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
        Dim Filter As IFilter, filterString As String, filterComparison As String, FilterCriteria As String, sanitizedFilterCriteria As
    String, PrimaryFilter As String, primarySchema As String,
    primaryTable As String, primaryKey As String, targetTable As String,
    targetField As String, Target() As String, filterItem As
    ControlDefinition_Filter

            Me.Dirty = False

            'Gather data for the primary filter from the active form

            With XFormToFilter
                .ResetFilter
                Set .FilterBuilder.FormToFilter = FormToFilter

                PrimaryFilter = IIf(.BaseFilter = vbNullString, _
                                        .NullFilter, _
                                        .BaseFilter)
                primaryTable = .FilterTable
                primaryKey = .key
            End With

            With Me.RecordsetClone
                If .RecordCount > 0 Then
                    .MoveFirst
                    Do While Not .EOF
                        'Get the schema, table/view, and control targetted by the filter
                        Target = Split(.fields("Field").Value, ".")
                        targetTable = IIf(Left(Target(0), 6) = "SELECT", GetTableName(Target(0)), Target(0))
                        targetField = Target(1)

                        filterComparison = Nz(.fields("Comparison").Value, vbNullString)
                        FilterCriteria = Nz(.fields("Criteria").Value, vbNullString)

                        Set filterItem = filterDict.item(.fields("Field").Value)
                        If filterItem.HasCriteria Then 'Get the stored equivalent for the criterion if available
                            sanitizedFilterCriteria = filterItem.GetCriteriaValue(FilterCriteria)
                            If sanitizedFilterCriteria <> vbNullString Then _
                                FilterCriteria = sanitizedFilterCriteria
                        End If

                        filterString = _
                            CreateFilterString(.fields("FieldType"), targetField, targetTable, _
                                                filterComparison, FilterCriteria)
                        filterString = FilterRegExp(filterString)

                        If Filter Is Nothing Then
                            Set Filter = XFormToFilter.FilterBuilder
                            Filter.SetPrimaryFilter PrimaryFilter, primaryTable, primaryKey
                        End If

                        Filter.AddSubFilter "Filter" & .fields("ID"), _
                            filterString, targetTable, subformDict(targetTable)
                        .MoveNext
                    Loop
                End If
            End With

            If Not Filter Is Nothing Then
                Dim finalFilter As String
                Filter.OpenFilteredRecordset
                XFormToFilter.SetFoundRecords

                DoCmd.Close acForm, "Filter_Create_popup", acSaveNo
            End If
        'error handling is here   
 End Sub`
```

Comment: You're not being clear.

Comment: Thanks. How about now?

Comment: Better.  So is your question "How do I guarantee that all 3 fields are filled," or "How do I use these fields to query the database?"

Comment: Well... querying the database is coded in the **Filter** button and I want to reference this **Or** to the **Filter** so that whenever filter is clicked, it looks whether the **Or** is clicked, if yes, then it filters using the tables in database. Simply, I'm just trying to make it just like any other Ors would function.

Comment: So you want to know how to refer to the fields on the form in the query?

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦ Yes, if that's how other Or features work! Otherwise I'm open in knowing how those are coded. I can't seem to find a good source to reference.

Comment: `Forms!NameOfMyForm.Form!NameOfMyField` <-- put that in your query grid, for your condition, in the appropriate column.  If you need a field chooser, you'll have to put `Forms!NameOfMyForm.Form!NameOfMyFieldSelectorCombo` at the top of a column in the query grid.

Comment: You should check out this tutorial: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/queries-iii-create-parameter-queries-that-prompt-users-for-input-RZ001097065.aspx

Comment: See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304302

Comment: @Robert Harvey thanks! The literature helps. Do I also have to do the  conditioning query even though it's done in my **Filter** button? I was just thinking to make a simple selection in **Or** and reference it to **Filter** button.

Answer (score 1):

I have an and feature search with a limited number of comboboxes (so I do not dynamically add them. See it this helps you on your way.

```
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim search_string As String
search_string = ""
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If ctrl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
        If ctrl.value <> "" Then
            If Len(search_string) > 1 Then
                search_string = search_string & " AND "
            End If
            search_string = search_string & LCase(Replace(ctrl.value, " ", "_"))
            If ctrl.Column(1) = "Number" Then
                search_string = search_string & " Like '*" & CStr(Me.Controls("Cval" & Right(ctrl.Name, 1)).value) & "*'"
            ElseIf ctrl.Column(1) = "Date" Then
                search_string = search_string & "=#" & Me.Controls("Cval" & Right(ctrl.Name, 1)).value & "#"
            Else
                search_string = search_string & " LIKE '*" & Me.Controls("Cval" & Right(ctrl.Name, 1)).value & "*'"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSearchResults", acNormal, , search_string
```

It loops through the controls and builds a filter string for the OpenForm event. Mine contains additional code to help with Data Types in my case.

Comment: Thanks, it helps to have a better idea.